# Reading data from zip files located in zip files with R

Tags: r, import

I'd like to use R to extract data from zip files located in zip files (i.e. preform some ZIP file inception).

An example "directory" of one of my datapoints looks like this:

```
C:\ZipMother.zip\ZipChild.zip\index.txt
```

My goal is to read in the "index.txt" from each ZipChild.zip. The issue is that I have 324 ZipMother.zip files with an average of 2000 ZipChild.zip files, therefore unzipping the ZipMother.zip files is a concern due to memory constraints (the ZipMother files are about 600 megabytes on average).

With the unzip package, I can successfully get the filepaths of each ZipChild located in the ZipMother, but I cannot use it to list the files located in the ZipChild folders.

Therefore,

```
unzip("./ZipMother.zip",list=TRUE)
```

works just fine, but...

```
unzip("./ZipMother.zip/ZipChild.zip",list=TRUE)
```

gives me the following error

> Error in unzip("./ZipMother.zip/ZipChild.zip", list = TRUE) : 
>    zip file './ZipMother.zip/ZipChild.zip' cannot be opened

Is there any way to use unzip or another method to extract the data from the ZipChild files?

Once I get this to work, I plan on using the ldply function to compile the index.txt files into a dataset.

Any input is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible example (i.e. a link to a zip file with the appropriate structure) would be useful, but how about:

```
tmpd <- tempdir()
## extract just the child
unzip("./ZipMother.zip",
        files="zipChild.zip",exdir=tmpd)
ff <- file.path(tmpd,"zipChild.zip")
index <- unzip(ff,list=TRUE)
unlink(ff)
```

This could obviously be packaged into a function for convenience.

It could be slow, but it means you never have to unpack more than one child at a time ...